# Firebase Firestore Dependency config problem

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am facing problem to add Firestore dependency. any kind of Firestore dependency create error, event the last. Here current dependency `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2`
after adding this dependency app is not running and i also trying firesrore: `16.0.0 and firestore:15:0.1` 
but it's nothing working.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

// FireBase
//noinspection GradleCompatible
**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'**

/*[This line create Error but i need firestore]*/ 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'

// Audience Network
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
// Required Dependency by Audience Network SDK
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'

// admob ad dependency
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'

// Tappx ad Dependency
implementation 'com.tappx.sdk.android:tappx-sdk:3.+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link, it may help:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
 }

 dependencies {
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
}
```